# Nested for/while loops and arrays, filtering out numbers from an array

Tags: c, arrays, loops, while-loop, nested

```
int main(void) 
{
int i,j=0,k;                               //initialization
char equation[100];                          //input is a string (I think?)
int data[3];                                 //want only 3 numbers to be harvested

printf("Enter an equation: ");
fgets(equation, 100, stdin);               //not so sure about fgets()

for (i = 0; i < equation[100]+1; i++) {            //main loop which combs through
                                                   //"equation" array and attempts
                                                   //to find int values and store
    while (j <= 2) {                               //them in "data" array
        if (isdigit(equation[i])) {
            data[j] = equation[i]
            j++;
        }
    }
    if (j == 2) break;

}

for (k = 0; k <= 2; k++) {                    //this is just to print the results
    printf("%d\n", data[k]);
}

return 0;
}
```

Hello! This is my program for my introductory class in C, I am trying to comb through an array and pluck out the numbers and assign them to another array, which I can then access and manipulate.

However, whenever I run this I get 0 0 0 as my three elements in my "data" array.

I am not sure whether I made an error with my logic or with the array syntax, as I am new to arrays.

Thanks in advance!!! :)

Comment: do you not want 0's in your array?

Comment: Well, unless the input string is 0 0 0! I am ALWAYS getting 0 0 0 instead of the actual string :(

Comment: This "for (i = 0; i < equation[100]+1; i++)" line is very strange. Mention the expected input and required output. So that it will be clear.

Comment: correct you should use equation.size() but I don't want to post something that they have not learned yet.

Comment: @ZumbaLover69 (rofl at 69) have you tried taking out the break; And see what you get?

Comment: @ZumbaLover69 also you are setting j = 0 every loop so your going to start at j = 0 and break a j = 0

Comment: @mahendiran.b I hope I made it more clear!!

Comment: @ExcelledProducts took it out and still getting 0 0 0!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code:

1. `for (i = 0; i < equation[100]+1; i++) {` should be something like

   ```
   size_t equ_len = strlen(equation);
   for (i = 0; i < equ_len; i++) {
   ```

   Whatever the input is, the value of `equation[100]` is uncertain, because `char equation[100];`, `equation` only has 100 element, and the last of them is `equation[99]`.
2. `equation[i] = data[j];` should be

   ```
   data[j] = equation[i];
   ```

   I suppose you want to store digit in `equation` to `data`.
3. `break;` should be deleted.

   this `break;` statement will jump out of the `while` loop, the result is you will store the last digit in `equation` to `data[0]` (suppose you have switched `data` and `equation`, as pointed out in #2).

   If you want the first three digits in `equation`, you should do something like

   ```
   equ_len = strlen(equation);
   j = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < equ_len; i++) {
           if (j <= 2 && isdigit(equation[i])) {
                   data[j] = equation[i];
                   j++;
           }
           if (j > 2) break;
   }
   ```
4. `printf("%d\n", data[k]);` should be `printf("%c\n", data[k]);`

   `%d` will give the ASCII code of `data[k]`, for example, if the value of `data[k]` is character '1', `%d` will print 50 (the ASCII code of '1') instead of 1.

---

Here is my final code, based on the OP code:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int i,j,k;
    char equation[100];
    int data[3];
    int equ_len;


    printf("Enter an equation: ");
    fgets(equation, 100, stdin);

    equ_len = strlen(equation);
    j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < equ_len; i++) {
        if (j <= 2 && isdigit(equation[i])) {
            data[j] = equation[i];
            j++;
        }
        if (j > 2) break;
    }

    for (k = 0; k <= 2; k++) {
        printf("%c\n", data[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Tested with:

```
$ ./a.out 
Enter an equation: 1 + 2 + 3
1
2
3
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I fixed my code but still ended up getting an error, this time it was the same number repeated 3 times, e.g., "50 50 50" regardless of input.

Comment: @ZumbaLover69 I have updated my answer, give it a try.

Comment: this was such a clean and simple solution. You're a savior, thanks.